# Add days to a datetime and convert it to a date ? - Odoo V14

Tags: date, datetime, odoo, crm

i want to add 30 days to a datetime field and make my date field take this value as default.

I tried this, but don't work :/

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

class crm_lead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    
    date_deadline = fields.Datetime(string='Fermeture prévue')
    
    @api.onchange('create_date')
    def _onchange_enddate(self):
        if self.create_date:
            date_end = ( datetime.strptime(self.create_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + relativedelta(days =+ 30).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )
            self.date_deadline = date_end.date()
```

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_date` is a [magic field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/models.py#L243) set in [_create](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/models.py#L243) method. To use the creation date as a default value for the `date_deadline` field, you can use the [default](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#models) attribute and use the [Date.today](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/fields.py#L1754) function to get the creation date.

***Example:***

```
date_deadline = fields.Datetime(default=lambda record: fields.Date.today() + relativedelta(days=30))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

class crm_lead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    
    date_deadline = fields.Datetime(string='Fermeture prévue')
    
    @api.onchange('create_date')
    def _onchange_enddate(self):
        if self.create_date:
            date_end = ( date.today()  + timedelta(30))
            date_deadline = date_end
```

It gives the current date + 30 days.

It does not strip the datetime variable, so you might want to do that after.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does'nt work... nothing appear

[the result](https://zupimages.net/up/21/10/q40q.png)

Comment: Of what type is the date that you try to add the 30 days? I am starting to think the problem is not adjusting the time but displaying it.

Comment: Yes it is the problem :) ! It's type is only called : "date"

Comment: I can not see what variable you are displaying. I do not have enough information to help you display the variable.

Comment: I hope this could help you : [photo](https://zupimages.net/up/21/10/sblp.png)

Here are the information of the field that i'm trying to change. btw i updatade my code to make it 'datetime' format (check update)

Comment: Okay, I see. You create a new variable called date_deadline by adding self. in front of it. If you wish to change that remove self., I adjusted my code as well, might be worth giving it a shot. And you might need to update the page after updating the date.